# How to use GeoServer in my LAMP stack with weekly data updates

Tags: geoserver, update, server, geoserver-rest-api

I need to make a Web GIS and weekly update all my data.

Currently I'm working on localhost with this work flow:

1. PostgreSQL (db with csv and shape)
2. GeoServer (to take data from db)
3. Qgis (get the layers from GeoServer and made elaboration)
4. LeafLet (create folder to do a webgis)
5. Put leaflet folder into my server.

I want to stop to load the leaflet folder into my server and do again the 5 steps above, all the time that I want just to update the csv (and shape).

Also I want that other peoople can access to the db on PostgreSQL and updating JUST the csv.

so Is it possibile with PostgreSQL doing all this?

Comment: Can you provide more information on the data.

Answer (score 1):

You should put your data in a Spatial database such as PostgreSQL/PostGIS; and you can periodically update this database with your data.

Then you should configure GeoServer to point to this database, setting up your WMS/WFS etc. services, the layers/featuretypes/coverages you want to serve, the projections you want the data to be available in, the output formats, and the styling...

Then you use Leaflet to build your Web GIS client to call these services provided by GeoServer.

Updates made to the database will immediately be available (through the services provided by GeoServer) in your Leaflet client.

If your data updates are just overwrites/amendments to the same collection of data, you won't need to be constantly reconfiguring GeoServer.

Comment: thank you so much for your precious comment. you solve my doubts! But if other people want to updating the data, how they can? They need postgreSQL and connect to the server?

Comment: How to enable others to remotely edit your data is probably a second question.   This is a general answer to your original question about how you as in individual data and service provider may configure your stack.  For your second question you will need to be specific about what your data is, whether you want others to edit, or completely overwrite, etc

Comment: The main data is a csv data that become a shape on qgis. I want that other people can updating more data into the csv and than the shape will be updating automatically

Comment: can you [edit](http://gis.stackexchange.com/posts/228858/edit) the question to add the additional information.